# placing arrow after each responsive card

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular11

I am working on angular app. I want to have responsive dynamic cards with arrow in between each card. my code is as follows:

```
<div class="col-4" style="width:25%" *ngFor="let element of myArray">
  <div class="card-body">
    </div>my card</div>
  </div>
</div>

myArray=[
{
  "id":1
},
{
  "id":2
},
{
  "id":3
},
{
  "id":4
}
]
```

This is creating responsive cards but after each card I want to add a arrow [arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z6sG.png) except last card. and cards should not go to another line and it should be responsive as before. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-4" style="width:25%"
     *ngFor="let element of myArray; let last = last">
  <div class="card-body">
    </div>my card</div>
  </div>
  <!-- your element with arrow (you can also put it inside div with clas "card-body", just use !last to hide arrow in last element -->
  <img src="./arrow.png" *ngIf="!last">
</div>
```